# get the uuid in an object array with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I would like to know if there would be a method to recover the uuid when I push data in my table I put you in the screenshot below

the code

```
push(ref(db, `/users/${auth.currentUser.uid}/user/sensors`), {
  name: registerInformation.nameBox,
  id: registerInformation.idBox,
  categories: registerInformation.categories,
  routine: registerInformation.routine,
});
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`push` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#push) returns a `Reference` object, from which you can get the `key` with something like this:

```
const newRef = push(ref(db, `/users/${auth.currentUser.uid}/user/sensors`), {
  name: registerInformation.nameBox,
  id: registerInformation.idBox,
  categories: registerInformation.categories,
  routine: registerInformation.routine,
});
console.log(newRef.key);
```

If you want to use that key in the write operation, you can also separate the creating of the new ID from the writing of the data like this:

```
const newRef = push(ref(db, `/users/${auth.currentUser.uid}/user/sensors`));
console.log(newRef.key);
set(newRef, {
  name: registerInformation.nameBox,
  id: registerInformation.idBox,
  categories: registerInformation.categories,
  routine: registerInformation.routine,
});
```

In this snippet, the first line is a pure client-side operation that doesn't actually write anything to the database yet.